# Problems identifying mail attachments in MimeKit with no content-disposition

Tags: email, mimekit

I have been trying to locate all attachments on an email that has inline attachments with no content-disposition.

This is a snippet of the email

> ```
> ----boundary_4451_1ea18041-d01e-46e2-8f88-32770bfba1b7
> Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=img0.png
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
> Content-ID: <image1>
>
> ..image base64 here..
> ----boundary_4451_1ea18041-d01e-46e2-8f88-32770bfba1b7
> ```

Have tried the Attachments collection but its obviously not in there.
Have also tried an approach where the "body" is identified and then everything else is treated as an attachment. However this picks up the html body as an attachment too because the headers for that are also suspect.

Any help appreciated or if you need more info please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MIME part that you've pasted the raw source for in your question will be located in `MimeMessage.BodyParts` because it is not tagged as an attachment via the `Content-Disposition` header, as you've noticed.

Every email client has its own idea of what constitutes an attachment and so it is up to you to decide how to determine if something is an attachment or not, that's not something that MimeKit can determine for you.

Have you checked out the `HtmlPreviewVisitor` sample code located in the [FAQ](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit/blob/master/FAQ.md)?

That sample code snippet shows you how to render an email message as HTML and gather up all of the referenced image attachments, etc. and it collects all of the other non-referenced attachments into an attachment list.

Comment: Makes sense. I'll take a look at the sample. Thanks.